# Changing a printf to a cout statement

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I'm trying to change a `printf` statement into an `std::cout` statement. How would I go about doing that for the following:

```
printf("\n %.2f Celsius = %.2f Fahrenheit", celsius, fahrenheit);
```

`celcius` and `fahrenheit` are both of `float` type, and `%f` comes from `scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);`.

Comment: Huh? you mean the `std::cout` stream of C++? This is a different language!

Comment: This may be heretical advice, but: maybe don't worry. `cout` is the C++ way and all, but you *can* keep using `printf` in C++ programs. (That's what I do.)

Comment: ^ by "different language" he means you used the C tag not C++ tag, and do not mention C++ in your text or title.  cout does not exist in C.  If you are using C++ you should fix the tag.

Comment: I think they want to know how that line would be converted to c++ print. it would be cout << " Celsius = " << fixed << setPrecision(2) celsius << " Fahrenheit = " << fixed << setPrecision(2) << fahrenheit << endl; this would require #include <iostream> #include <iomanip> & using namespace std;

Comment: For OP's code example it's better to stay on using `printf`.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with C. Both `printf` and `cout` are C++.

Comment: @melpomene: `printf` is originally from the C standard `<stdio.h>`; of course it is available in C++ thru `<cstdio>`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, but it still exists in the C++ standard library in `<cstdio>`. I don't think a C programmer could help answer this question, and of course this problem does not occur if you're only using C.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) from [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) header to achieve this.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// printf("\n %.2f Celsius = %.2f Fahrenheit", celsius, fahrenheit);

int main()
{
    const float celsius = 10.555;
    const float fahrenheit = 50.999;

    std::cout << '\n'
              << std::fixed
              << std::setprecision( 2 )
              << celsius << " Celsius = "
              << fahrenheit << " Fahrenheit";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 10.56 Celsius = 51.00 Fahrenheit

Here's the live example: https://ideone.com/ElJ0Wg

But, this is not as compact as it is with `printf`. However, there's this formatting library ([`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)) that tries to achieve the compactness of `printf` along with other good stuff. And, AFAIK, it has been proposed to be included in the C++ standard library. So, IMO, it would be a good idea to explore and use it in your projects.

Comment: you forgot " << std::endl " at the end of your stream ;) (for OP : std::endl is adding an end of line char to your string AND call flush() to sync your stream.

Comment: @Pellekrino: Thank you for your input! Actually, I tried to stick to answer the problem at hand. There might be stream flushing issue depending upon the OP's use case and I'm sure there are pretty good answers on SO to that problem.